# binary search in java little error

Tags: java

```
int m, l, f, k = 4;
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

f = 0;
l = a.length - 1;
m = (f + l) / 2;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[m] > k) {
        f = 0;
        l = m - 1;
    }
    if(a[m]<k) {
        f = m + 1;
        l = a.length - 1;
    }       
    m = (f + l) / 2;
}
if(k == a[m]) {
    System.out.println("found");
} else {
    System.out.println("not found");
}
```

when i put k=4 and k=6 it says not found....?????
may i know wht positions need to be correct

Comment: Debug your code and you'll know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
    int middle;
    int right;
    int left;

    int k = 1;

    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    left = 0;
    right = a.length - 1;

    middle = (left + right)/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
        if(a[middle] > k) {
            right = middle - 1;
        }
        if(a[middle] < k) {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
        middle=(left + right)/2;
    }

    if (k == a[middle]) {
        System.out.println("found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not found");
    }
```

Also you should pay more attention for your variable names. Names like `i, k, m, a` are really misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The errors are here:

```
if(a[m] > k) {
    f = 0;             // Error number one
    l = m - 1;
}
if(a[m]<k) {
    f = m + 1;
    l = a.length - 1;  // Error number two
}
```

Your code for binary search should not adjust both ends of the range. Instead, only one end should be adjusted.

In addition, your code does not cover the case when `a[m] == k` correctly, meaning that when you find your item, your code would continue looping until reaching the end of the `for` loop (see below).

Finally, the loop should stop when `f == l`, not when `i` reaches `a.length` (and it should be a `while` loop, not a `for` loop).

Comment: In addition, while this isn't strictly an error, the termination condition of the loop is... weird. There's no need to loop an amount of times equal to the number of items in the list. Just loop until the interval is closed or the item is found.

Comment: *In addition, your code does not cover the case when `a[m] == k`* -- Technically, it does, since none of the conditions match and nothing therefore happens. It will just keep looping until the counter reaches the irrelevant stop and then determine that the item was found.